# ComboBox created in runtime won't show Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I need to create at runtime a combobox containing persons' name, populate it with a data array, and bind its opening to a button.
Even if I set the height, it won't open. It doesn't exists in the XAML file, it has to be created by runtime.

Whenever I debug the Height, it is always set to 0;

```
ComboBox peopleComboBox = new ComboBox();
List <Person> people; //it's initialized elsewhere
private void btnLoadPeopleName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        peopleComboBox.IsEnabled = true;
        peopleComboBox.Height = 1280; //I wanted to set it Auto with double.NaN but it won't open. Always set to 0 during debugging.

        peopleComboBox.ItemsSource = people;
        peopleComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "first_name";
        peopleComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

        peopleComboBox .SelectionChanged +=peopleComboBox_SelectionChanged;

        peopleComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        peopleComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true; //this should open it, right?
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you add the combobox to the view?

Comment: I didn't think about that. I thought it could be opened just like that. What should I do?

Comment: I've added it and now it works like a charm, thanks. I'll set correct @Vishnu Prasad's answer because I can't do it on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @ChrisF comment, are you adding this comboBox to your view? If not add it to a parent Container component.
`gridComponent.Children.Add(yourComboBox)`

As for the `Height` what you're doing is correct.

Comment: I've added it and now it works like a charm, thanks. I'll set correct your answer because I can't do it on @ChrisF comment.